# "big" Data csv search from 2 files

Tags: python, csv, bigdata

I have an computational problem.

I'm using python to iterate over 2 csv files.

csv file1=  contains (6-7) columns .. and the important column is an "rs ID" column from dbSNP.

csv file2= 3 columns, 2 of them are important, also the rs ID and a GENE symbol column

my problem:

now i want to search: is an rs ID from csv file 1 IN csv 2 ? if yes, take the gene symbol from csv file 2 and put it into csv file 1 where the match occured (position "x", e.g. row 4512451).

csv file 1= 1,3 gb, csv file 2 = 8.8 mb

i'm generation a dictionary in python  from the csv file 2 and I use it to search in csv file 1.

Problem: for every row(rs ID) in the csv file 1, he iterate through the whole dictionary ( 8.8mb file)

That takes way to much time.... do you know an another approach to get this search faster? I thought a dictionary/hashtable would be good... but it is way to slow.

Maybe creating a Suffix Array from csv file 2 instead of using a dictionary?

Or are there some packages, other data structures in python (vectorization methods)?

I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) it supports very fast loading of csv data, index and value lookup and insertion of values from another dataframe where conditions are met, at this stage your question is a bit broad, I think you should look at pandas try a few things and come back when you get stuck

Comment: if i read my csv file with : tp = read_csv('endParsedNOgene.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=10000) # gives TextFileReader, which is iteratable with chunks of 1000 rows.
df = concat(tp, ignore_index=True)         The process get kileld

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading both CSV files into memory? 1.3 GB still seems to be manageable. Than you can put both CSV files into data structures that are much better suited for your problem.

If you choose to do that I would recommend using [pandas DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) as a container. They can [be directly constructed from CSV files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html). Your search can than be performed quite fast using [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

Comment: no, the process got killed, so it seems i cant load the whole file into the memory with tp = read_csv('endParsedNOgene.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=10000) # gives TextFileReader, which is iteratable with chunks of 1000 rows.
df = concat(tp, ignore_index=True)